# My code works with input files, but doesn't with others. (Debug Assertion Error)

Tags: c++, string, vector

Write and test a program that prompts the user to input a file name and a string to test for. Search the file for every occurrence of the specified string – when the string is found, display the line that contains it. When all occurrences of the string have been found display the number of times the string appeared in the file. Hint: You may use string member function find().

Here's my code, as I stated it works with some sentences but not all, it doesn't seem to have anything to do with the length either as if I repeat a line I know works, it won't run into any errors, can someone explain?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

void find_common_words(string, int);
vector<string> words;

int main(){ 
    vector<string> line;
    string input;
    char filename[50];
    ifstream inputFile;
    cout << "Enter File Name:" << endl;
    cin.getline(filename, 50);
    inputFile.open(filename);
    //TESTING IF FILE IS OPEN
    if (!inputFile.is_open()){
        cout << "File Wasn't Opened!" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    while (getline(inputFile, input)){
        line.push_back(input);
    }
    int size_of_array = static_cast<int>(line.size());
    
    for (int i = 0; i < size_of_array; i++){
        istringstream iss(line[i]);
        int word_number = 0;

        do {
            string word;
            iss >> word;
            words.push_back(word);
            word_number++;
        } while (iss);
    }
    string commonword;
    cout << "Enter a word to search for (without punctuation)" << endl;
    cin >> commonword;
    int size_of_array2 = static_cast<int>(words.size());
    find_common_words(commonword, size_of_array2);

    return 0;
}

void find_common_words(string search, int sizeofarray2) {   
    //CONVERSION TO STRING WITHOUT PUNCTUATION
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeofarray2; i++){
        string temp_string = words[i];
        for (int j = 0, len = temp_string.size(); j < len; j++){
            if (ispunct(temp_string[j])){
                temp_string.erase(j--, 1);
                len = temp_string.size();
            }
        }
        words[i] = temp_string;
    }
    //SEARCHING FOR SAME WORDS
    int line_number = 1;
    int words_found = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeofarray2; i++){
        if (search == words[i]){
            cout << search << " Was found on line " << line_number << endl;
            words_found++;
        }
        if (words[i].length() == 0){
            line_number++;
        }
    }
    cout << line_number - 1 << " lines checked, " << words_found << " matches " << endl;
}
```

Heres my input file (randomly generated):

```
It's a very big deal.
Carl won the spelling bee and got a trophy!
Why is your cat so big?
Do you have a big bowl I can borrow?
It's a big company.
Penguins live in the Antarctica.
Don’t be silly, you're going to the game!
What are you talking about?
He threw up in the trash can!
You're so ratchet!
But she is a good caretaker.
Tom is looking for a bigger house to live in.
```

I get an error with Debug Assertion
Expression c> = -1 && c < = 255

Comment: Compile your code using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` then use both [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/) and [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) to understand the behavior of your executable. Consider installing [Debian](http://debian.org/) on your laptop, if so allowed. See also [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) for *every* function, `class`, type or operator you are using and did not define

Comment: I'm genuinely curious what happens when you replace this: `if (ispunct(temp_string[j]))` with this: `if (std::ispunct(static_cast<unsigned char>(temp_string[j])))`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch That is a great comment for a newbie. To recommend valgrind and gdb is a really good idea to recommend to people who just start to learn to write C++ code. I am always happy to see such good comments. Thank you and +1

Comment: @WhozCraig it actually looked like it fixed the problem.

Comment: I'm guessing you have a non-ascii character in your input somewhere, paying a char directly to `ispunct` only works for ascii characters, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/ispunct

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Good news! I found the solution. And all this without valgrind, gdb and deleting windows and reinstalling debian. I also did not check the complete cppreference. So, not *every* function, class type or orperator. Isn't that great? And compiling with clang and gcc wit ````-std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -g```` does also not show any error . . .  Wow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I debugged the program and WhozCraig is right. In your input text in the line

```
Don’t be silly, you're going to the game!
```

In the word "Don’t", you  do not have the normal apostrophe as you have in the word "It's" or "you're"

This special character is encoded as -110 in temp_string. In the description of [std::ispunct](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/ispunct) you can read:

> The behavior is undefined if the value of ch is not representable as unsigned char and is not equal to EOF.

-110 does not fit and causes a debug assertion error. If you cast it to `unsigned char` like WhozCraig proposed, it will work.

You can also fix your input file.

A very interesting and subtle error . . .